# Nav bar not taking background color

Tags: html, css, nav

My navbar is not taking background colour because of background colour the whole page?
Can you explain why is this happening and how to fix this?

```css
* {
  background-color: rgb(245, 244, 182);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav {
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>about</li>
    <li>contact us</li>
    <li>services</li>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Becuase your HTML is invalid, an `li` must have a `ul` as a parent.

Comment: Also "spcificity".

Answer (score 0):

Use `body` instead of `*` and it will work.

If `*` is used as an independent selector, it means all. That means it will apply the styling to all elements. You should also use `<ul>` to surround your `<li>` elements.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(245, 244, 182);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav{
    background-color:red;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>about</li>
        <li>contact us</li>
        <li>services</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: what is the diff between main and *? I gave bg colour to my button and it worked but in nav it didn't can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

the "*" select every elements, it's good for the "box-sizing".
But not the best to apply a background-color at your full page ("body" or "html").

(I had some padding, display inline and hide the list style in your css :)

```css
  * {
             box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background-color: rgb(245, 244, 182);
        }
        
        .nav{
            background-color:red;
            border: 2px solid blue;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        ul {
        list-style: none;
        }
        
        li {display: inline;
        background-color: green;
        padding: 4px 10px;}
```

```html
         <header>
                <nav class="nav">
                    <ul>
                       <li>home</li>
                       <li>about</li>
                       <li>contact us</li>
                       <li>services</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
```